# Yahoo Weather API current conditions

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-weather-api

I am trying to get the current weather conditions for a certain location, but for some reason I always get the conditions for a semi-random day/time (more or less past week). I am using this query: `https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20item.condition%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20%3D%20639660%20AND%20u%3D%22c%22&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=`
Even trying out the example query on their [website](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/) doesn't work for me. When I click on "Current conditions for San Diego, CA" I get the same, random results. Is there any way to get the current conditions?

Comment: ? what does `yahoo.finance.quote` have to do with weather?

Comment: My fault, I am working with multiple yahoo APIs and copied the wrong url. Should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same thing.  It has to be on Yahoo's side.  Unfortunately it looks like their support page is down too.  Returned a 404

Answer (score 0):

I've also notice the random ( 1 day up to 2 wks) of old data being transmitted 
http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss/55364_f.xml  It seems to change about every 30 seconds

Comment: If you post an answer then please answer the question: " Is there any way to get the current conditions?"  Simply observing that the person who asked the question is correct in his/her observations does not help much.